# How to extract data from json and pass as props in Next.js

Tags: json, reactjs, next.js

I am currently stuck in this situation:

1. I need to pass `props` to the component to fill the `DataGrid`
2. Therefore, i'm using `getStaticProps` to get JSON data from an API and then return as props.
3. However, I only need 3 attributes from each entry of the JSON file and I **must** pass only those 3 attributes as props to the `DataGrid`

**Question**: How do I extract the 3 json attributes from each entry (approx 50 entries) into my own JSON object. Then, return the JSON object as props?

#### My current code:

```
  export async function getStaticProps(){
  const res = await fetch ('https://api.link.example')
  const data = await res.json()

  return{
    props: {
      data
    },
  }
}
```

#### Component Code

```
export default function dashboard({data}){
return (
    <Layout>
    <div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
        <DataGrid rows={data}  /*material UI kit*/
        columns={columns} 
        pageSize={5} 
        checkboxSelection 
        disableSelectionOnClick="true" />
    </div>
    </Layout>
)
```

}

#### Sample JSON

```
[{"total": 121227292170, 
"high": 74886, (require)
"low": 71316, (require)
"price": 2847.93, (require)
"price_change": 3.95671,},

{"total": 121227292170, 
"high": 74886, (require)
"low": 71316, (require)
"price": 2847.93, (require)
"price_change": 3.95671,}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
let data = await res.json()

data = data.map(item => {
    
     const { price, high, low } = item
     return { price, high, low }
})
```

.map will loop through all the objects, the return statement will return only the keys you want.

Comment: you are a total lifesaver!